# Laravel Eloquent still throwing error with updated_at column even I ignored it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a website using Laravel 5.2. I am working with database. So I used Laravel eloquent model to make the code neat and clean. But one of my Eloquent is throwing `unknown updated_at column exception` even if I already ignored it.

I ignored or override the built in function like this in my Entity.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'mm_name'];

    public function setUpdatedAt($value)
    {
    // Do nothing.
    }   

    public function setCreatedAt($value)
    {
    // Do nothing.
    }   
}
```

I deleted `updated_at` column from categories table. So if I update the category, `updated_at` column should be ignored.

So updated like this

```
function updateCategory($bag)
    {
        $category = Category::find($bag->id);
        if($category)
        {
            $category->name = $bag->name;
            $category->mm_name = (empty($bag->mm_name))?$bag->name:$bag->mm_name;
            $category->save();
        }
    }
```

But it still throwing this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `categories` set `name` = sdsd, `mm_name` = sdsd, `updated_at` = 2016-02-20 11:36:41 where `id` = 4)
```

I overrode the other tables and eloquent entity like that. That is all working, but this one is not. How can I fix that?

This is the screenshot of categories table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the `created_at` or `updated_at` fields, you need to set the `$timestamps` property on your model to false. Additionally, you don't need to override the `setUpdatedAt()` or `setCreatedAt()` methods.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'mm_name'];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

If `$timestamps` is true, the Eloquent query builder will add in the `updated_at` field whenever you update a model.

Answer (score 0):

- Your mutator defination is wrong. it should be **setUpdatedAtAttribute**
  and **setCreatedAtAttribute**
- There was no need to delete the updated_at and deleted_at attributes from the database.
- You have deleted the attributes from the database so there is no need for **setUpdatedAtAttribute** and **setCreatedAtAttribute** in your model. Laravel will include them as columns in your database.
- Will advice you recreate the updated_at and created_at in the categories table and if you are using mysql 5.7 ensure that your timestamps are not 00-00-00 00:00:00 that is if you are manually created them(not recommended to manually create them).